# parameter has no default value vb net access

Tags: vb.net

before that, i'm sorry if my english is too bad
help me please, i'm beginner to vba access, i want to insert multiple photos to access but it's always error in here "Parameter Has No Default Value" in "Parameter @image1 has no default value."

i have 2 table, "datapenjualan" and "datagambar", datapenjualan is parent table, and datagambar it's child table, NoFaktur is Primary Key on 2 table
when i input data in datapenjualan, NoPesanan Automatic input to datagambar too.

so now i can't input 5 photos to my table

here my codes

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class insertpicture
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim conString As String
    Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
    Dim arrImage1() As Byte
    Dim arrImage2() As Byte
    Dim arrImage3() As Byte
    Dim arrImage4() As Byte
    Dim arrImage5() As Byte
Private Sub Form6_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Visible = "False"
    PictureBox2.Visible = "False"
    PictureBox3.Visible = "False"
    PictureBox4.Visible = "False"
    PictureBox5.Visible = "False"
End Sub

Private Sub save_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_button.Click
    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ajeng Shaffira\documents\visual studio 2010\Filling Data\Filling Data\DatabaseTransaksiPenjualan.mdb"

    If nofaktur.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Input No Pesanan!")
    ElseIf IsNothing(PictureBox1.Image) Then
        MsgBox("Select image 1!")
    ElseIf IsNothing(PictureBox2.Image) Then
        MsgBox("Select image 2!")
    ElseIf IsNothing(PictureBox3.Image) Then
        MsgBox("Select image 3!")
    ElseIf IsNothing(PictureBox4.Image) Then
        MsgBox("Select image 4!")
    ElseIf IsNothing(PictureBox5.Image) Then
        MsgBox("Select image 5!")
    Else

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = conString
            con.Open()
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            command.CommandText = "insert into datagambar([FakturInvoice], [SPB&BAPP], [PurchaseOrder], [TandaTerimaInvoice], [FakturPajak]) VALUES (@image1, @image2, @image3, @image4, @image5)"
            command.Connection = con
            command.Parameters.Clear()
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@image1", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = arrImage1
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@image2", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = arrImage2
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@image3", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = arrImage3
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@image4", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = arrImage4
            command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@image5", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = arrImage5
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()****((((here it is my error))))
            MsgBox("Pictures Saved!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            command.Dispose()
            con.Close()
            Call bersih()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

please help mee :((

Comment: Huh? You're talking about Access VBA, but this is clearly VB.Net code. That's not going to fly if you're actually using VBA, those are different languages.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know this is vb net, I'm really really sorry, I will edit it again. Thank you for advice

Comment: I don't see where you're assigning anything to `arrImage1` or the any of the rest of those `Byte` array variables.  They are presumably `Nothing` and that's your issue.  You need to actually create `Byte` arrays from your `Images` and assign them to those fields.